# Syncing bookmarks across different web browsers

Tags: bookmarks

I am trying to sync bookmarks across my different (firefox, chrome, safari) web browsers. While I'm not successful at syncing across browsers, but it does sync across same browser on multiple devices as long as I sign in with same email id.
Fyi..I am using same email id to login to my different web browser.
1)Do anyone know if this type of sync is possible without installing any third-party extentions/addins?
2)If third party extention is a must then which one is good?
3) Are these bookmarks stored at browser level or email id level? I think browser otherwise it would have synced.